# Question from isi previous years

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, binomial-coefficients

(a) Show that $\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\ k\end{array}\right)=\sum_{m=k}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}m-1 \\ k-1\end{array}\right)$.

(b) Prove that
$$
\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
1
\end{array}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
2
\end{array}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
3
\end{array}\right)-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
n
\end{array}\right)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}
$$

I was thinking mathematical induction for the second part that is,,,

Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(n):\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
1
\end{array}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
2
\end{array}\right) &+\frac{1}{3}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
3
\end{array}\right) \cdots+(-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
n
\end{array}\right) \\
&=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots \frac{1}{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
$P(1):\left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)=1$.
$P(1)$ true.
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(2):\left(\begin{array}{l}
2 \\
1
\end{array}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{l}
2 \\
2
\end{array}\right) \\
=& 2-\frac{1}{2}=1+\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
$P(2)$ is also true.
Let $p(k)$ tque $\Rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{l}k \\ 1\end{array}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{l}k \\ 2\end{array}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\left(\begin{array}{l}k \\ 3\end{array}\right) \cdots+(-1)^{k+\frac{1}{k}}$ Now we try to show $p(k+1)$ will be true $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots \frac{1}{k}$ $P(k+1)=\left(\begin{array}{c}k+1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c}k+1 \\ 2\end{array}\right)+\cdots(-1)^{k} \frac{1}{k+1}\left(\begin{array}{l}k+1 \\ k+1\end{array}\right)$

I cannot argue from here,,, please help me for both part. Thank you.

Comment: I would guess that the two questions are together because the questioner wants to use the first in the second, but I can't be sure. It looks like you've included (a) without trying (a), so maybe you just accidentally included it?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can do induction here, because you can use $\binom{k+1}i=\binom{k}{i}+\binom{k}{i-1},$ but then the coefficient ahead of $\binom{k}{i-1}$ will be wrong for the induction. You are going to need a different technique.

Comment: Which year question is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we seek to evaluate

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}{n\choose k}.$$

We introduce the function

$$f(z) = n! (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{z} \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{z-q}.$$

We have for $1\le k\le n$ that

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=k} f(z) =
n! (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}
\prod_{q=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k-q}
\prod_{q=k+1}^n \frac{1}{k-q}
\\ = n! (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}
\frac{1}{k!} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}
= \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}{n\choose k}.$$

It follows that the desired sum is given by

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm{Res}_{z=k} f(z).$$

Now residues sum to zero and the residue at infinity is zero by
inspection. Therefore the sum must be equal to

$$S_n = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z)
= - n! (-1)^{n-1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
\prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{z-q}
\\ = n! (-1)^n
\left.\left(\prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{z-q}\right)'\right|_{z=0}
\\ = n! (-1)^n
\left. \prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{z-q}
\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{q-z} \right|_{z=0}
= n! (-1)^n \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} H_n
\\ = H_n = 1+ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: Great :) please give hint or solution for (a)

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch of a proof using Mathematical Induction**:

Recall the identity (well-known, easy to prove)
$$\binom{n + 1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k - 1}. \tag{1}$$

For (a):

Using (1), we have
$$\sum_{m=k}^{n + 1} \binom{m-1}{k-1} = \sum_{m=k}^{n} \binom{m-1}{k-1} + 
\binom{n}{k-1} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1} = \binom{n+1}{k}.$$

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

For (b):

Using (1), we have
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}}{k}\binom{n+1}{k}\\
 =\, & \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}}{k}\binom{n+1}{k} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n + 1} \\
 =\, & \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}}{k}\binom{n}{k}
 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}
 + \frac{(-1)^n}{n + 1} \\
 =\,& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}}{k}\binom{n}{k}
 + \frac{1}{n + 1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}(n + 1)}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}
 + (-1)^n\right)\\
 =\,& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}}{k}\binom{n}{k} + \frac{1}{n + 1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k - 1}\binom{n + 1}{k}
 + (-1)^n\right)\\
 =\,& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}}{k}\binom{n}{k} + \frac{1}{n + 1}\left(1 -  \sum_{k=0}^{n + 1} (-1)^{k}\binom{n + 1}{k}\right)\\
 =\,& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k - 1}}{k}\binom{n}{k} + \frac{1}{n + 1}
\end{align*}
where we have used the binomial theorem (letting $x = 1$)
$$(1 - x)^{n + 1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n + 1} (-x)^{k}\binom{n + 1}{k}.$$

We are done.

Comment: Great :). Please give hints or solution for (a)

Comment: @Sonu For a), you may use Mathematical Induction and $\binom{n + 1}{k} = \binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k - 1}$.

Comment: Okay :)... @river li